# JS changes don't appear on localhost, need to restart IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

IIIS version 10.0.19041.320. Project ASP .NET MVC or Core project, don't know where to find the version.

As a newbie, I spent a week trying to see modifcations on my js files.
As I change their content I cannot see the change on localhost. I have the same path of folders wwwroot/scripts/app/modules/components/ui/xxx.js
they appear but with no change
The only way to see changes is to restart IIS, quite a tour de force...

Those js files don t look compiled, minified, etc. In the browser I call them with the same filename.js and their content have the same formating.

At the opposite no problem with html file, the change are reflected on the server instantly.
Html files are in Areas/Styleguide/Views/Default/

Same on any IDE, Visual code or Jetbrains Rider.

I tried to change:
· Hot reload
· Server cache in xml config file
· Js file > properties > Build action
· Deleting C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET

If you have any clue,,, thxxx I can't work like this !

Comment: try ctrl+f5 to pull fresh js files.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you want to force this js file to update at the client, you could add a ? to the script's src link.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>
```